# How to access that value from database which is inside switch expression

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
SqlCommand objSelectCommand1 = new SqlCommand("Select mainMenuNum , mainMenuData from [menudatas] WHERE [ivrNumber]=10000 ;", objConnection);
SqlDataReader dataReader = objSelectCommand1.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string data = null;
dt.Load(dataReader);
```

here xml variable in switch expression will contain different value every time because it is based on user input.

I want to compare value of xml variable from database and fetch relevant data, then print that data. But it is not retrieving any data from database.

```
switch (xml)
{
    case 0:
        TextToSpeech("No information on 0 button");
        break;
    case 1:
        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select mainMenuData from [menudatas] WHERE [mainMenuNum] = '" + xml + "' && [ivrNumber]=10000 ", objConnection);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                data = dataReader.GetString(0);
            }

       } 
       dataReader.Close();
       Console.WriteLine(data);
       break;    
}
```

Any help would be apreciated. Some one please suggest me an answer!

Comment: Are you sure your SQL  (With the where clause) is returning records ?

Comment: Data is present in all these columns but still not fetching any data

Comment: Switch statement says `xml` is integer and in sql query you are putting it in single quotes.